# Upload Photo Using HTML5

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, post, base64, image-uploading

I'm developing a HTML5 and jQuery based iPad application.I need to upload an image to the server.
The server url is https://myserver.myclient/myproject/uploadphotos

I need to have the request data like below 
{
  "FileName": "abc.jpg",
  "FileDescription": "Description of file",
  "FileData": "Base64 encoded String",
  "LibraryId": "libraryId",
  "FileTitle": "First File"
}

The HTML code part for file upload section is as below,

```
<tr>
          <td class="ui-table-priority-1">
            <div class="ui-input-text ui-shadow-inset ui-corner-all ui-btn-shadow ui-body-c ui-input-has-clear">
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" value="" data-clear-btn="true" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c">
                <a href="#" class="ui-input-clear ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-fullsize ui-btn-icon-notext ui-input-clear-hidden" title="clear text" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-mini="false"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">clear text</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></span>
                </a>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="ui-table-priority-2">
          </td>
        </tr>
```

I was able to get the parameters like filename,filedescription,filetitle and library id.
I need to get the base64Encoded String for "File Data" and also the code for posting the same to the server.

Please help me out in uploading the photo.The project I'm woking is using HTML5,jQuery Mobile and JavaScript only.

Thanks in advance,

Abin

Answer (score 0):

For interracting with webcam using HTML5, you can check out this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463874/Webcam-and-Annotation-With-HTML5

For base64 encoding, check this thread:
[How can you encode a string to Base64 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript)